# Are there any good movie/film APIs out there?

Tags: api, movie

Working on a movie website and would love to find an API that I could use to get information about different movies.  I code in PHP but I'm assuming this would probably return XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend [themoviedb.org](http://www.themoviedb.org/).  We have been using their [API](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.0/docs/) in an open source movie managing application with great success.

Comment: Do you know if you can use the API on desktop applications(lots of users)?

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search returned this: <strike>[Internet Video Archive Movie API](http://api.internetvideoarchive.com/MovieAPI.aspx)</strike>. It seems to return XML data, so it could work for you.

EDIT: The link is down (thanks @Mutant), Wayback Machine has [a backup](http://web.archive.org/web/20090211033739/http://api.internetvideoarchive.com/MovieAPIAvail.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For getting straight-up information about movies (for instance, basic genre and title information) the Amazon associates data works pretty good.  There is the condition that the data be used primarily to drive traffic to Amazon, which is something to keep in mind.

There should be a PHP library already written that you can use: http://aws.amazon.com/associates/

Answer (score 0):

[Rotten Tomatoes](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/) has a free REST API ([developer.rottentomatoes.com](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com)). The access keys are restricted to [10000 calls/day](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/forum/read/123466).